# display icons depending on array elements with vue js

Tags: vue.js

I receive for places to rent an array with amenities like that :

```js
["dishwasher", "kitchen", "washer_dryer", "tv", "parking", "family", "pets"]
```

and i would like to display an icon for some of them. i tried the v-for solution, but it seems a bit weird to loop over all elements to display only one or two.

```html
<div v-for="amenity in amenities">
    <img v-if="amenity === 'pets'" src="/petsicons.png"/>
</div>
```

I have my icons in the static folder as img's.

**What would be the more efficient way to do that in vue js ?**

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: Would you like to display text for all of them and only an icon for some ? Or just an icon when its existing ?

Comment: just an icon for some of them when it's existing indeed

Answer (score 0):

here some working example with v-for, you can use v-if to filter like this.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
          <button @click="moreImage" >+</button>
          <div v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index">
            <img v-if="index === 2" :src="`https://picsum.photos/400/400?image=2${index}`" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <script>
          var app = new Vue({
                    el: '#app',
                    data: {
                      images: [1],
                    },
                    methods: {
                      moreImage() {
                        // make push to get more load index
                        this.images.push(1)
                      }
                    }
                 })
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

hope this helps, thank you